# Troubleshoot connection with packet loss

Tags: networking, router, isp, fiber

I've been having packet loss issues while playing online, so I've decided to do the PingPlotter test to the game IP.

The hop 4 seems to have a massive packet loss problem, but that's the ISP server and it does not bother me that much.

[image]

The problem is the second hop, which is from my router to my ISP, which is fiber optics.

Could there be a problem with my fiber optics installation? or is 0,15% packet loss from my router to my ISP normal? I thought it should be 0% using fiber optics.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on what else is happening on your home network. If you are the only one using it for testing then there is likely an issue with the fibre, but if others are using the connection that could cause the issue.

It's also possible that the ISP has oversubscribed the connection, and that this is hidden by encapsulation of data packets.

Comment: Any other ways to test if the fibre is faulty? I've tried pinging only the 1st hop after the router and there's an average of 0.15% packet loss.

Comment: If the packet loss is consistently .15% that would seem to me to be an issue your ISP should be looking into for you.